# mysql update groupwise max

Tags: mysql, groupwise-maximum

I have the following table

```
 CREATE TABLE `data` (
`acquire_time` decimal(26,6) NOT NULL,
`sample_time` decimal(26,6) NOT NULL,
`channel_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
`value` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
`status` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`connected` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`channel_id`,`acquire_time`),
UNIQUE KEY `index` (`channel_id`,`sample_time`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

For each channel_id I would like to find the row with the maximum acquire time and change value to NULL, status to NULL and connected to 0. Is this possible? The manual says that you cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery...

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update data join
(
    select channel_id, max(acquire_time) acquire_time
    from data
    group by channel_id
) x on x.channel_id = data.channel_id and x.acquire_time = data.acquire_time
set
    value = null,
    status = null,
    connected = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
update data data_1
set value = null, status = null
where not exists (
    select 1
    from data data_2
    where data_2.channel_id = data_1.channel_id
    and data_2.acquire_time > data_1.acquire_time 
)
```

If that doesn't work, try this:

```
update data as data_1
left join data as data_2
on data_2.channel_id = data_1.channel_id
and data_2.acquire_time > data_1.acquire_time
set data_1.value = null, data_1.status = null
where data_2.acquire_time is null
```

Comment: The first one gives: You can't specify target table 'data_1' for update in FROM clause.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Sorry, I took Richard's, it was just a little bit clearer to me how it worked, but I think the second one here works too.